# Native SQL in Doctrine: set types of multiple query parameters

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I'm using NativeSQL and I need to set an undefined number of parameters. My code:

```
$entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();
$rsm = new Query\ResultSetMappingBuilder($entityManager);
$mySql = "
   SELECT *
   FROM table1 t1
   INNER JOIN table2  t2 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
   ...
   WHERE t1.name = :t1_name AND t2.age = :t2_age AND ...
";
// array of multiple query parameters (name, value)
$queryParameters = array(
   't1_name' => 'Andy',
   't2_age' => 12,
   ...
);
$query = $entityManager->createNativeQuery($mySql, $rsm);
$query->setParameters($queryParameters);
$salidas = $query->getResult();
```

I need to set the type of every query parameters but setParameters() function doesn't allow pass this types.

I see that setParameter() function of AbstractQuery (Doctrine class) allow pass this types, but I would like to use setParamaters() function because I have to pass an undefined number of paramaters...

How can I solve this? Thanks.

Comment: What does It mean "I need to set the type of every query parameters" ?

Comment: The type of WHERE parameters. In my example: :t1_name (string type) and :t2_age (integer type). For example, something like: [PDO bindParam()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php#refsect1-pdostatement.bindparam-examples)

Comment: Why do you need this? To me, it looks like your question has the [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): asking about your attempted *solution* rather than your *actual problem*.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass multiple parameters to your query using the following:

```
$entityManager = $this->getEntityManager();

$sql = "
   SELECT *
   FROM table1 t1
   INNER JOIN table2  t2 ON t2.t1_id = t1.id
   ...
   WHERE t1.name = :t1_name AND t2.age = :t2_age AND ...
";

// array of multiple query parameters (name, value)
$stmt = $entityManager->getConnection()->prepare($sql);

$stmt->execute([
    't1_name' => 'Andy',
     t2_age' => 12,
    ...
]);

$results = $stmt->fetchAll();
```

**Reference** [Data Retrieval And Manipulation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-dbal/en/latest/reference/data-retrieval-and-manipulation.html)